# javascript function that changes text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a slider using Slick and I want to change the left and right arrows text into (next and prev) after hovering on it. How can i do this using a javascript function ?

```
<div class="left-slider-arrow slider-arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="right-slider-arrow slider-arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>


$(".left-slider-arrow").click(function(){ 

 //now which text to change? 

 });
```

Comment: that's not slider, that's carousel as i think.

Comment: $(".left-slider-arrow").click(function(){ //now which text to change? });

Answer (score 1):

just edit slick-theme.css, watch line 89 and 107

```
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}
```

replace '←' to "nedded text"...